# How to traverse through the diagonals?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

It's giving outOfBounds every time. I have tried every possible alteration now but it's not giving the output. The O/P should be 7-4-8-1-5-9-2-6-3

```
 for(int g=n-1; g>=0; g--) {
        for(int i=g, j=0; i>=g; i++, j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    
    for(int g=0; g<n; g++) {
        for(int i=0, j=i+g; j<n; i++,j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]) ;
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the first thing you can do is change the i>=g to a better limit.
As you are incrementing i positively, and i is already equal to g, it will keep going up past the limit of the array's bounds. Maybe i<(the limit of your bounds) should solve it.

If I was trying to iterate through a square matrix, I would use only one variable and iterate with a[i][i] to reduce confusion:

```
for (i=0; i > (your bounds); i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i][i]);
}
```

This is the base logic but you seem to be trying to achieve something a little more advanced, so modify it as you see fit.

Comment: If I get it correctly, OP wants to print all sequences of array items in slant lines (diagonals) parallel to the main diagonal. That is items `a[i][i+h]` within valid range of `i` for all reasonable values of `h`.